# find the trace of a $D^{-1}$ in $A=(B+C)D^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, positive-definite, block-matrices, circulant-matrices

Let

$$B := \begin{bmatrix} j H & kH \\ kH & H\end{bmatrix}$$

where $H$ is a circulant matrix and it is symmetric and non-invertible, and $j, k$ are scalars. Let

$$A := (B+C)D $$

where $C$ is a skew-symmetric matrix and $D$ is a positive definite matrix. Everything is real-valued.

I would like to find the trace of $D$ in terms of $A$, $H$, $j$, $k$. Could anyone please help me to solve the question?

several observations:

Firstly: B is symmetric and non-invertible, and is a Kronecker product of $\begin{bmatrix} j  & k \\ k & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $H$

Secondly: $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=\operatorname{Tr}(BD)$

Comment: @ToniMhax is there anyway to prove that it is impossible?

Comment: Even with $C=0$, and say $D^{-1}$ is diagonal you would try it is not doable generally and $j>1$.

Comment: @ToniMhax thank you for the reply, i just edited the question to make it simpler.

Comment: Where does this question come from? Is it homework or did you come up with it yourself? If you answered the second part affirmatively, how did you come up with it?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik it is some research

Comment: The problem is that $\text{Tr}(A)=\text{Tr}(BD)+\text{Tr}(CD)$, upon diagonalizing $D$ by some unitary matrix $U$ we assume that $D$ is diagonal, $\text{Tr}(CD)=0$ as you noticed (the diagonal of $C$ is zero) now $\text{Tr}(BD)$  for $j\neq 1$ is not easy to split...

Comment: @ToniMhax thank you for the reply, what if j = 1, is there anyway to split ?

Comment: $j=1$ the diagonal of $H$ is $c_0I$ so $\text{Tr}(A)=\text{Tr}(BD)=c_0\text{Tr}(D)=\frac{\text{Tr}(B)}{2n}\text{Tr}(D)$. Dimension of the matrices is $2n$.

Comment: @ToniMhax Thank you for the answer, why is $Tr(BD)=c_{0}Tr(D)$?

Comment: The diagonal of $H$ is $c_0I$ multiplied by diagonal $D$...

Comment: @ToniMhax Thank you for the answer, but I still don't understand you. $Tr(BD)=\Sigma B_{ij}D_{ij}$ since B is symmetric, so surely the other elements of B except the diagonal element will contribute to Tr(BD). Can you be more specific about your proof? Thank you.

Comment: No problem, $H$ is circulant the diagonal is a scalar $c_0$

Comment: $D$ is diagonal by a unitary matrix if you don't get it i'll put full answer. or explain

Comment: @ToniMhax H is circulant the diagonal is scalar $c_{0}$, I agree with this. But what do you mean by D is diagonal by a unitary matrix, and where the unitary matrix comes from? It would be great if you can put a full proof, thank you very much.

Comment: Ok my fault, this works only for $D$ diagonal if not as you said other elements are in.

Comment: @ToniMhax okay, D is a postive-definite matrix and it is not a diagonal matrix